# Send Array of Json from Ajax to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I try to send an array of json objects from the javascript to a Php code. Unable to get a response from the php file.

```
function getData() {
    var jsonObject = [];
    var genderMenu = document.getElementById("gender");
    var levelMenu = document.getElementById("level");

    jsonObject[0]  = { 
        psid: document.getElementById("psid").value,
        fName: document.getElementById("fname").value,
        lName: document.getElementById("lname").value,
        gender: genderMenu.options[genderMenu.selectedIndex].value,         
    };

    for(var i = 1; i <= varCount; i++) {
        if(document.getElementById("fName"+(i))) {
            jsonObject[i] = {fName : document.getElementById("fName"+(i)).value,
            lName: document.getElementById("lName"+(i)).value, 

        };
        }
    }

    var jsonObjectString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
    var result = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/inviteProcessing.php',
        data: {myData: jsonObject},
        success: function(response) {
                  if(response.success)
                    alert(response.message);
                  else
                    alert(response.message);
              }
    });

  alert(jsonObject);
}
```

Php File has the following code

```
<?php   
$input = $_POST['myData'];
$input_string = json_decode($input, true);
echo json_encode( array('success' => true, 'message' => $input_string) );
?>
```

Do u see any problem?

Comment: What is the problem? What do you see in the console?

Comment: What do you see in the console? Is the file path /inviteProcessing.php correct?

Comment: What does "Unable to get response from the PHP file" mean? Blank page? Then go find the error (see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info for debugging white screens). Otherwise debug the inputs. No one can help you much past that.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to echoing your output, try...

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $encodedjsonstring;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put `exit` or `die()` at the end of php file

Answer (score 0):

Please try below points.

1. First check if path of the php file is correct.
2. Then add below line in ajax call.

   type: 'POST',

   dataType: "json", //add dataType

   url: '/inviteProcessing.php',

   data: {myData: jsonObject},